# Rails 7 Import Maps - How do I inject a script into HTML template?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

In rails 6 with webpacker you could throw in a `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'alerts' %>` in a view or template to inject some js.

How does this work with import maps and rails 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the code is correctly in the import map, you can reference it with:

```html
<script type="module">import "/assets/custom/alerts.js";</script>
```

Presuming the file is `app/javascript/custom/alerts.js`

Referenced in `config/importmap.rb` as:

```rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

And imported into the application.js:

```js
import "custom/alerts"
```

---

Edit: I now think this is an antipattern in Rails 7. It is very easy to use Stimulus controllers instead.

[Stimulus Handbook](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/hello-stimulus) For reference

For example, to dismiss an alert when a user clicks the "x"

```
// app/javascript/alerts_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    dismiss () {
        this.element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div data-controller="alerts">
    <h2> Alert! </h2>
    <span data-action="click->alerts#dismiss"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
</div>
```